# Hooking RX to TX to create echo server

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I just bought a bluetooth module from Sparkfun http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10253[RN-42](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10253)

I have the power, ground, and tx,rx lines soldered onto and ready, I don't have a working TX/RX microcontroller solution at the moment, however I was wondering if I could connect the rx to the tx lines, so if I connect using BlueTerm https://market.android.com/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm and try to type something to the bluetooth, I want it to just echo it back (as a test).

Would something like this work/make sense? Or will there be voltage/other issues? (I don't have a PC with bluetooth or serial support, so really my phone is the only option atm)

Thank you,
Tyson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I got impatient.....I just hoooked the TX and RX lines together and I get direct echos. Hope this helps anyone else that might want to know.

Comment: You can mark your answer as correct

Comment: @onaclov2000, sorry, it normally takes a little bit for answers but looking at this I could have said it would work, wonder why no one answered.

Comment: I need to wait till tommorrow to mark it as correct, and I completely understand that I'm just plain impatient, I was just looking for a confirmation more then anything...LOL